# how to create new user only if there is data in database-Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have done programming with other frameworks but this is new to me, thanks for your time in advanced, I'm trying to create new user on a condition that if there is data in another table then new user is created otherwise not I have put my code inside if else statement and is throwing errors.

my function for creating new user is listed below:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        /*$exists = \DB::table('received_pay')->where('email', $data['email'])->first();  */
          $exists=\DB::table('received_pay')->where('email', '=', $data['email'])->where('token', $data['token'])->exists();


if ($exists === null) {
   // user doesn't exist



        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'token'   => $data['token'],
        ]);

}else{
    return null;
}

}

}
```

[this is the error it throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlI5N.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `User` instance from the `RegisterController@create` method by default, you can't return `null`. So, do this instead of `return null;`:

```
return User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();
```

If it's an option to check if the user exists in the `users` table, you can use the `firstOrCreate` method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::firstOrCreate(['email' => $data['email'], [
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'token' => $data['token'],
    ]);
}
```

Also, you if want to check if a user exists in the `received_pay` table, you can leave original `RegisterController@create` method and add this rule to the `RegisterController@validator` method:

```
'email' => 'unique:received_pay,email',
```

This will not allow Laravel to create a new user if a user with the same email already exists in the `received_pay` table.

Comment: Thanks Alexey Mezenin, I did not elaborate correct, I have two tables the first one is the user table which have these property id, username, email,remember_token, createdat, updateat another table is called received_pay having id, email, token my task is to check if the email, and token entered by the user must match the ones in received_pay otherwise new user is not created.  Thanks I'm going to use your solution above and let you know how it went.

Comment: I have accepted the solution but I've no enough reputation, It is not showing. Thanks.